# How to pre-populate 9 with jQuery Masked Input Plugin?

Tags: jquery, mask, maskedinput

I am using Masked Input Plugin from digitalBush for jQuery, which is very simple to use.

For some cases, I want to pre-populate data for the client, so for something like this :

```
.mask("123999")
```

client will see:

```
123___
```

And will need to insert last 3 digits. It's working fine till the moment I want to pre-populate number 9, to show something like this:

```
129___
```

When I am making mask as `"129999"`, user see `12____`

Is it even possible to have mask with this plugin that is visible for the user as `129___`?

Comment: Have you tried appending a new value (using `.val()`) to the text box after the plugin is initialized?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can redefine masked input definitions like this:

```
$.mask.definitions['9'] = '';
$.mask.definitions['d'] = '[0-9]';
```

And then use this mask:

```
.mask("129ddd")
```

Comment: I still can't find a solution for this